# Join two arrays and get tuple

Tags: c#, linq

let's say I have two collections:

```
string[] arr1 =
{
    "item-1",
    "item-2",
    "item-3",
    "item-777",
    "item-4"
};

string[] arr2 =
{
    "item-1",
    "item-2",
    "item-3",
    "item-4"
};
```

TODO: when arr1 element does not match to arr2 element, return: arr1[i] = "empty". return type: IEnumerable<(string, string)>.
result should be:

```
item-1 - item-1
item-2 - item-2
item-3 - item-3
item-777 - empty
item-4 - item-4
```

My solution doesn't works:

```
IEnumerable<(string, string)> result = arr1.Join(arr2,
                                      item => item,
                                      item => item ?? "empty",
                                      (item1, item2) => (item1, item2));

foreach (var item in result)
{
  Console.WriteLine($"{item.Item1} - {item.Item2}");
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Can either array contain duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

With `HashSet<T>` you can "quickly" find if given item exists in second array. `Join` method will use HashSet in "background" anyway.

```
var others = arr2.ToHashSet();
var pairs = arr1.Select(item => (item, others.Contains(item) ? item : "empty"));

foreach (var pair in pairs)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{pair.Item1} - {pair.Item2}");
}
```

Comment: it doesn't works. return type should be: IEnumerable<(string, string)>

Comment: A `(string, string)[]` is an `IEnumerable<(string, string)>`.

Comment: @DeveloperMister, it works, named tuple is `Tuple` anyway and can be consumed as Tuple with `Item1` and `Item2` properties  and array is implementing `IEnumerable` ;)

Comment: Working and clean solution +1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes these things are just easier to write with the other syntax

```
IEnumerable<(string, string)> result =  from a1 in arr1
                                    join a2 in arr2 on a1 equals a2 into j
                                    from a2item in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                    select (a1,a2item ?? "empty");
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tFMNxA

---

In method syntax it uses `GroupJoin` and `SelectMany`

```
var result =  arr1.GroupJoin(arr2, a1 => a1, a2 => a2, (a1,a2) => (a1,a2))
                  .SelectMany(x => x.a2.DefaultIfEmpty(), (x,y) => (Item1:x.a1, Item2: y?? "empty"));
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MbBIyQ

Comment: can you please give a solution in Method syntax too? @Jamiec